# Password Regex with XRegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords, xregexp

I have a client-side validation regex for a password field which should allow alphabets in all languages supported by Unicode.

This is the existing regex for password:

```
(?=^.{8,21}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])
```

I am using the XRegExp library, and i have tried modifying the regex to include \p{L} but I am unable to get it to pass for passwords like "Ss!11111".

Below is my modified regex:

```
(?=^.{8,21}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*\\p{L})
```

I know this question might seem stupid, but i currently have very little time to experiment with this regex. Would be really helpful if someone helped me out and pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double all the backslashes:

```
(?=^.{8,21}$)((?=.*\\d)|(?=.*\\W))(?![.\\n])(?=.*\\p{L})
```

Also, I'm not sure of that regex makes much sense. Is this really what you want:

```
(?=^.{8,21}$)  # Assert length 8-21 characters (why only 21?)
(              # Group 1:
 (?=.*\\d)     # Assert at least one digit in the string
|              # OR
 (?=.*\\W)     # at least one non-alnum character in the string
)              # End of group 1
(?![.\\n])     # Assert that the *first* character isn't a dot or newline (??)
(?=.*\\p{L})   # Assert at least one letter in the string
```

Comment: nice catch..also i guess `(?![.\\n])` should be `(?!.*[.\\n])`

Comment: awesome, i can't believe that was the fix, haha. And yes, that is the regex required, including a max of 21 chars :)